# Select max value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi dimensional array created dynamically like the one below

```
Array
    ( 
[50] => Array
    (
        [Paracetamol] => Array
            (
                [name] => Paracetamol
                [qty] => 10

            )

        [count] => 2
        [Loratidine] => Array
            (
                [name] => Loratidine
                [qty] => 15

            )

    )

[51] => Array
    (
        [Paracetamol] => Array
            (
                [name] => Paracetamol
                [qty] => 10

            )

        [count] => 2
        [Loratidine] => Array
            (
                [name] => Loratidine
                [qty] => 15

            )

    )

[52] => Array
    (
        [Paracetamol] => Array
            (
                [name] => Paracetamol
                [qty] => 10

            )

        [count] => 1
    )
```

)

I want to select the index values for the items with the highest value of count. Count is a measure of how many elements are in the sub array apart from the count itself.

How do I go about?

Comment: Does this mean that count == how many items are in the array i.e. paracetamol and loratidine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$max_count = 0;
foreach ($array as $a) {
    if ($a['count'] > $max_count) $max_count = $a['count'];
}
// if you want to copy the elements with count == max_count, leaving the original array alone
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $a1) {
    if ($a1['count'] == $max_count) {
        $new_array[] = $a1;
    }
}
// if you want to remove the elements with count < max_count from original array
foreach ($array as $index => $a1) {
    if ($a1['count'] < $max_count) {
        unset($array[$index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. Create function like so:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) return 0;
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

and then call the following method to order the array based on count.

```
uasort($array['count'],'cmp');
```

Depending on whether $a > $b or $a < $b this can change the count from either Ascending or Descending order.

So the first item in the array will have the highest count value.

Comment: if there are multiple elements with the same highest value of count, how would I select them?

Answer (score 0):

For just selecting index keys of array elements with the highest value of '`count`' key(descending order):

```
$counts = [];
array_walk($arr, function($v, $k) use (&$counts){  // $arr is your initial multidimensional array
    $counts[$k] = $v['count'];
}, $counts);

arsort($counts);   // Now the $counts is an array in which keys are real indexes from your initial array and values are the highest values of 'count' column in descending order
```